# How to remove duplicates from the xml in faster manner

Tags: c#, xml

Suppose we have an xml like

`<texts>
    <text top="9" style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:7;" left="671">Page:</text>
    <text top="9" style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:7;" left="671">Page:</text>
    <text top="9" style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:7;" left="671">Page:</text>
    <text top="9" style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:7;" left="671">Page:</text>
    <text top="9" style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:7;" left="720">1</text>
    <text top="9" style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:7;" left="720">1</text>
    <text top="9" style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:7;" left="720">1</text>
    <text top="9" style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:7;" left="720">1</text>
</texts>`

How to remove the duplicate values from the xml in faster manner. The filtering can be made according to the top and left attributes while the number of duplicates are not fixed.

Comment: Faster than what? What have you tried?

Comment: @Tim I have tried with for and foreach but they are taking ages while the records are big in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fastest way will be to use the Linq `Distinct` method which internally uses a `HashSet` to compare each value. You have to write a custom `IEqualityComparer` like this.

```
    XElement textsElement = ...;
    var newTextsElement = new XElement("texts", texts.Elements().Distinct(new TextElementEqualityComparer()));

    private class TextElementEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<XElement>
    {
        public bool Equals(XElement x, XElement y)
        {
            return x.Attribute("top").Value == y.Attribute("top").Value
                && x.Attribute("left").Value == y.Attribute("left").Value;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(XElement obj)
        {
            return obj.Attribute("top").Value.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Attribute("left").Value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Linq-XML` to parse the XML and create a list. Traverse that `list` and remove unwanted (double) elements.

Answer (score 0):

what you do is very possibly a foreach in a foreach.
--> means O(n^2)

what you could do is to Hash each row and add the hash value to a dictionary. If you Hash a value which exists already in the dictionary you know you have a duplicate and you dont add it.

should be O(n + log(n)) which is way better (i assumed O(log(n)) for the dictionary access)